# How I can use ruby-git to recursively clone a remote repo?

Tags: ruby, git

How can I use [ruby-git](https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git) to recursively clone a remote repo?

I use this code:

```
require "git"
Git.clone "git://github.com/user/repo.git", "/tmp/repo"
```

but this does not recursively clone the repo from GitHub.

I need an analog for:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/user/repo.git /tmp/repo --recursive
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementation of the `#clone` method in ruby-git tells us that it is currently impossible:

https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git/blob/master/lib/git/lib.rb#L44

```
def clone(repository, name, opts = {})
  @path = opts[:path] || '.'
  clone_dir = opts[:path] ? File.join(@path, name) : name

  arr_opts = []
  arr_opts << "--bare" if opts[:bare]
  arr_opts << "-o" << opts[:remote] if opts[:remote]
  arr_opts << "--depth" << opts[:depth].to_i if opts[:depth] && opts[:depth].to_i > 0

  arr_opts << '--'
  arr_opts << repository
  arr_opts << clone_dir

  command('clone', arr_opts)

  opts[:bare] ? {:repository => clone_dir} : {:working_directory => clone_dir}
end
```

You better fork ruby-git and insert a couple of lines there. It will solve your problem and the world will say "thank you".

Comment: Thank you, I followed your recommendations and added to the existing library to my pull-request (https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git/pull/58)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the simplest path is to let the app do it itself. Why not use?

```
`git clone git://github.com/user/repo.git /tmp/repo --recursive`
```

Comment: It was first thought, but since my program is filled with the correct code is (in my opinion), I decided to continue to go the right way and not to use exec / system.

Comment: Go the "right way"? How is it wrong to use the tools available to you, especially when something you want to do isn't available the "right" way? Code regularly uses `exec` and `system`; If those were "wrong" they wouldn't be available.